Flutter-Dart 'print' and 'log' not printing to console in Android Studio
I tried to print to console but can't get it to work. I have  checked other forums and tried their recommendations but no result.
import 'dart:developer';

log('your message here'); // nothing

or
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

debugPrint('your message here'); // nothing

Filtering "your message here" in the Android Studio logcat shows nothing. I'm just learning Flutter. I need help.

You will find it on the Run section of your Android Studio. Moreover, importing 'package:flutter/material.dart'; will be enough to find debugPrint(). Hope you'll find your log, happy coding!

@TryCatchFinally nice to meet you. 
I also needed a feature like Logcat, so I created one. 
It's called flutter_logcat package. 
You can find more details on Pub.dev site. 
I hope it has the features you're looking for. 
If it does, that would make me really happy. 
If you need any enhancement features, feel free to request them on GitHub issues, and I'll work on it! 
Thanks!
Add
flutter pub add flutter_logcat


Usage
import 'package:flutter_logcat/flutter_logcat.dart';

@override
void initState() {
  ...
  Log.d("Test initState..");
}


https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_logcat

If you add a print statement or log, please check the output in the Android Studio terminal or the debug console. When running your app in debug mode, view the logs in the debug console; otherwise, check the terminal for your logs.


